# How to bind List<string> to gridview inside another gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I just wanted to bind the below List object to Grid view. That list contains another List. So when I bind the datasource, that column is coming as EMPTY.

Details below:

```
List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
public class Person
{
    public string Name1;
    public string Name2;
    public List<string> Address;
    public DateTime DateOfBirth;
    public string TeamName;
}
```

I assigned my gridview as below:

```
var data = new List<Persons>();
data = GetData();
GrdPerson.DataSource = data;
GrdPerson.DataBind();
```

Since we have address as `List<string>` in datasource, it is coming as empty in page.

I know that Address does not contain any public property hence it is coming as empty. So I tried to use Gridview in Address column of Master Grid.

But do not know how to assign the datasource at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the gridview's `RowDataBound` event to DataBind the inner grid:

```
protected void GrdPerson_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Person person = (Person)e.Row.DataItem;
        GridView innerGrid = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GrdPersonAddresses");
        innerGrid.DataSource = person.Address;
        innerGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```